# How to calculate acceleration of an object in 3D using Matlab spaps?

Tags: matlab, validation, velocity, acceleration

I have x,y,z data for birds flying.

```
5.41634053198718    -18.1810946096409   -0.780385429905346
5.35578033638605    -18.1270442655634   -0.776694225482939
5.28687303433952    -18.0715127366784   -0.771968693273565
5.22280640780212    -18.0183932558829   -0.754602789629705
5.15964035792608    -17.9643849978555   -0.745350176350257
5.09014224340910    -17.8968959680244   -0.731112510479869
5.02017144713341    -17.8157826681313   -0.716412745992774
4.94927907542683    -17.7428283683055   -0.705797975911837
4.88058887728044    -17.6828866166493   -0.695765115125014
4.81567941240209    -17.6178084266463   -0.687394977780229
```

I want to know the kinematic properties of the flight trajectory. Currently, I have tried using smoothing with Matlab spaps function to generate a quintic spline, as is often been done in the literature. I use the spline to generate 1st and 2nd derivatives (velocity and acceleration). This yields the following:

Velocity (m/s)

```
7.53445215021684
8.69441552364295
8.81064845682925
8.18234102569862
8.90947412371613
10.6002874957899
10.6624464789766
9.82686835741751
8.47284851350541
11.3409318153158
```

Linear Acceleration (m/s^2)

```
183.838635562134
102.230396070086
217.935743093510
166.277761581847
195.859134993080
177.605911374232
133.877969039041
111.044847076448
83.5303968061012
691.158834476335
```

Velocity seems like realistic values, but I do not have experience with calculating acceleration and these values seem wildly high. I even tried just using the equations for velocity and acceleration (time between positions is 0.01 because data were sampled at 100 fps). Papers of other flying animals do not seem to have accelerations this high but I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Can anyone shed some light here? Am I just going about this incorrectly? How can I verify my answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you look for example at the first two elements of your velocity array, they differ by `1.159963373426111m/s` in `0.01s`, so it is kind of consistent with accelerations of the order of hundreds of m/s^2. Whether this is possible or not for your flying animals I can't tell.

On the other hand, keep in mind that velocities and accelerations are always vector quantities, while I guess you're just looking at the magnitude?